# Why does fixing a small spelling issue in my answer clear the vote count?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, edits, voting

I've done the following:

1. [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872187/generic-property-how-to-specify-the-type-at-run-time/2872205#2872205) a question
2. Got a vote - +10 rep
3. Fixed my answer because of a spelling mistake.

Now when I look at the vote count I get 0 - and my rep is back to where it started.

Does this mean that when you edit an answer the votes are reset? Why?

Or - the voter just canceled his vote and it happened to be at the exact time I've edited my answer?

Comment: I guess this is about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872187/generic-property-how-to-specify-the-type-at-run-time/2872205#2872205 then? (Just in case Jeff et al might want to peek into the logs to ensure nothing odd happened?)

Comment: @Arjan, yes, about that question.

Comment: If the original vote was more than 5 (?) minutes old then the voter would have had to wait until you edited the answer to revoke the vote.

Comment: @ChrisF, I believe it wasn't that old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a cancelled vote, yes. Edits don't reset the vote counters. And a downvote would have a different overall rep-change.